# displaying sprites after Collision detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So when I shoot the enemies they get wiped from the screen, this works.

However what I want to happen is I want to place an explosion (4 pngs one after another)
basically where the enemy was. The code for the explosion works on its own but im stuck trying to integrate it with my code.

Here is the explosion class, as you can see I am having some trouble with the interval as I have no experience with them. I think the error or wrong logic lies in this object.

Also for some reason it wipes the other canvas layers :/
Try it here: http://www.taffatech.com/DarkOrbit.html

```
function Explosion()
{
this.srcX = 0;
this.srcY = 1250;
this.drawX = 0;
this.drawY = 0;
this.width = 70;
this.height = 70;
this.currentFrame =0;
this.totalFrames =5;
this.hasHit = false;
}

Explosion.prototype.draw = function() //makes it last 10 frames using total frames
{

if(this.currentFrame <= this.totalFrames)
{

   this.currentFrame++;
  Exploder(this.drawX,this.drawY);
}

else
{
   this.hasHit = false;
   currentFrame =0;

}

}


function Exploder(srcX,srcY)
{
  whereX = this.srcX;
   whereY = this.srcY;
 intervalT = setInterval(BulletExplosionAnimate, 80);
}

var bulletExplosionStart = 0;
var whereX =0;
var whereY =0;

function BulletExplosionAnimate(intervalT)
{


var wide = 70;
var high = 70;

if (bulletExplosionStart > 308)
{
  bulletExplosionStart = 0;
 clearInterval(intervalT);
}
else
{
ctxExplosion.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight)
ctxExplosion.drawImage(spriteImage,bulletExplosionStart,1250,wide,high,whereX,whereY,wide,high);
bulletExplosionStart += 77;
}


}
```

my Bullet object:

```
function Bullet() //space weapon uses this
{
this.srcX = 0;
this.srcY = 1240;
this.drawX = -20;
this.drawY = 0;
this.width = 11;
this.height = 4;
this.bulletSpeed = 10;
this.bulletReset = -20;

this.explosion = new Explosion();
}

Bullet.prototype.draw = function()
{

this.drawX += this.bulletSpeed;
ctxPlayer.drawImage(spriteImage,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
this.checkHitEnemy();

if (this.drawX > canvasWidth)
  {
  this.recycle();

  }

}

Bullet.prototype.fire = function(startX, startY)
{

   this.drawX = startX;
   this.drawY = startY;

}

Bullet.prototype.checkHitEnemy = function()
{

    for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
    {
       if( this.drawX >= enemies[i].drawX && this.drawX <= enemies[i].drawX + enemies[i].enemyWidth && this.drawY >= enemies[i].drawY && this.drawY <= enemies[i].drawY + enemies[i].enemyHeight)
        {

        this.explosion.drawX = enemies[i].drawX - (this.explosion.width/2);
        this.explosion.drawY = enemies[i].drawY;

        this.explosion.hasHit = true;
        this.recycle(); //bullet resets after hit enemy
        enemies[i].recycleEnemy(); //change this soon to have if loop if health is down 
        }


    }

}


Bullet.prototype.recycle = function()
{

    this.drawX = this.bulletReset;

}
```

In my player object I have a function that checks if it has hit an enemy, it works:

```
Player.prototype.drawAllBullets = function()
{

  for(var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++)
   {
     if(this.bullets[i].drawX >= 0)
     {

       this.bullets[i].draw();

     }

     if(this.bullets[i].explosion.hasHit)
     {
     this.bullets[i].explosion.draw();
     }

   }
}
```

Currently when I shoot an enemy they disappear but not explosion happens, I know my interval is not great coding, so I need some help with it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Playing a spritesheet in canvas**

It’s becoming best practice to use requestAnimationFrame to do your animations.  It does some nice event grouping and performance enhancing.  Here’s a good post on requestAnimationFrame:  http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/

This is how you can use requestAnimationFrame to play a spritesheet:

In this case, it’s a 4x4 spritesheet that will play over 1 second:

```
var fps = 16;
function explode() {

    // are we done? ... if so, we're outta here
    if(spriteIndex>15){return;}

    // It's good practice to use requestAnimation frame
    // We wrap it in setTimeout because we want timed frames
    setTimeout(function() {

        // queue up the next frame
        requestAnimFrame(explode);

        // Draw the current frame
        var x=spriteIndex%(cols-1)*width;
        var y=parseInt(spriteIndex/(rows-1))*height;
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(sheet,x,y,width,height,0,0,width,height);

        // increment the sprite counter
        spriteIndex++;
    }, 1000 / fps);

}
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/nSGyx/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        // This is Paul Irish's great cross browser shim for requestAnimationFrame
        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
          return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
          function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
        })();

        // define the spritesheet
        var spriteIndex=0;
        var width=64;
        var height=64;
        var rows=4;
        var cols=4;

        // load the sheet image
        var sheet=document.createElement("img");
        sheet.onload=function(){
            canvas.width=width;
            canvas.height=height;
            // call the animation
            explode();
        }
        sheet.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/explodeSprite.png";


        var fps = 16;
        function explode() {

            // are we done? ... if so, we're outta here
            if(spriteIndex>15){return;}

            // It's good practice to use requestAnimation frame
            // We wrap it in setTimeout because we want timed frames
            setTimeout(function() {

                // queue up the next frame
                requestAnimFrame(explode);

                // Draw the current frame
                var x=spriteIndex%(cols-1)*width;
                var y=parseInt(spriteIndex/(rows-1))*height;
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                ctx.drawImage(sheet,x,y,width,height,0,0,width,height);

                // increment the sprite counter
                spriteIndex++;
            }, 1000 / fps);

        }

        $("#explode").click(function(){ spriteIndex=0; explode(); });

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=64 height=64></canvas><br>
    <button id="explode">Explode</button>
</body>
</html>
```

.
.
.

**[Edited to show more details of how animation fits into your code]**

This is a recoding of your explosion functions.

Declare your explosion related variables outside the functions:

```
var bulletExplosionStart;
var whereX =0;
var whereY =0;
var wide = 70;
var high = 70;
```

Next, in Exploder(), set where the explosion will occur and reset the sprite index (bulletExplosionStart) to 0

**Possible error:**  Check your Exploder function: you supply srcX,srcY but then do whereX=this.srcX, whereY=this.srcY.  I assume you meant to use the srcX,srcY supplied as arguments to Exploder() instead of this.srcX,this.srcY.

```
function Exploder(srcX,srcY)
{
    whereX = srcX;
    whereY = srcY;
    bulletExplosionStart=0;
    BulletExplosionAnimate();
}
```

This is the recoded bulletExplosionAnimate function that plays the 4 frames of the spritesheet.

After  4 frames this animation automatically stops.

```
var fps = 2;
function bulletExplosionAnimate() {

    // are we done? ... if so, we're outta here
    if(bulletExplosionStart>308){return;}

    // It's good practice to use requestAnimation frame
    // We wrap it in setTimeout because we want timed frames
    setTimeout(function() {

        // queue up the next frame
        requestAnimFrame(bulletExplosionAnimate);

        // Draw the current frame
        ctxExplosion.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight)
        ctxExplosion.drawImage(spriteImage,
            bulletExplosionStart,1250,wide,high,
            whereX,whereY,wide,high);

        // increment the sprite position
        bulletExplosionStart += 77;
    }, 1000 / fps);

}
```

Comment: ...and as far as your Hull/Shield disappearing, try setting the z-index of your canvasXY higher.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I tried what you said but Im getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'draw
you can try it at: http://www.taffatech.com/DarkOrbit.html
It wont even draw the first frame of the animation, I know I havent make the other ones draw yet by changing the x srcX value by +77 each frame, but it wont show anything

Comment: See the addition to my answer showing how requestAnimationFrame would fit into your code.

Comment: Thanks again, Now no error shows(thanks) But no animation plays either, here it in action uptodate: http://www.taffatech.com/DarkOrbit.html

Comment: From the limited view I have of your code, the Exploder function does not seem to be called when the enemy is destroyed.